# Написать функцию, которая находит все 5-ти значные числа сумма цифр,которых ровна введенному значению

Tags: python-3.x

Помогите, пожлста, написать указанную функцию. Не знаю, что дальше. Нужно число разбить на цифры и если сумма этих цифр = введенному числу, то вывести все комбинации 5-значных чисел.

```
n = int(input("Input number: "))
def total(n):
    mylist = []
    summa = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
```

Comment: Ну как же не знаете - сами же написали - "число разбить на цифры". Перебираете числа в диапазоне 10000..99999, разбиваете и проверяете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sum_of_digits(number):
    return sum(int(i) for i in str(number))


def get_numbers(digits_sum):
    return [i for i in range(10000, 100000) if sum_of_digits(i) == digits_sum]

print(get_numbers(3))
```

---

```
[10002, 10011, 10020, 10101, 10110, 10200, 11001, 11010, 11100, 12000, 20001, 20010, 20100, 21000, 30000]
>>>
```